# Build cannot find entity framework

Tags: c#, build

When I build my project in TFS it cannot find the entity fraemwork, yet when I look in the folder it is there;

I get these error messages;

```
Build started 14/02/2013 15:44:50.
Project "C:\Builds\1\SCD\SCD - New Test\Sources\MVC\SCD\SCD.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\Builds\1\SCD\SCD - New Test\Sources\MVC\SCD\SCD.sln" (1) is building "C:\Builds\1\SCD\SCD - New Test\Sources\MVC\SCD\SCD\SCD.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources:
Skipping target "EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources" because it has no outputs.
EntityDeployEmbeddedResources:
  Processing 1 EDMX files.
  Starting to process input file 'Models\SCD.edmx'.
  Finished processing input file 'Models\SCD.edmx'.
  Finished processing 1 EDMX files.
Project "C:\Builds\1\SCD\SCD - New Test\Sources\MVC\SCD\SCD\SCD.csproj" (2) is building "C:\Builds\1\SCD\SCD - New Test\Sources\StandardClassLibrary\StandardClassLibrary\StandardClassLibrary.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "EntityFramework".
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\Builds\1\SCD\SCD - New Test\Sources\StandardClassLibrary\StandardClassLibrary\StandardClassLibrary.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\EntityFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\EntityFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\EntityFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

And so on. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: "when I look in the folder it is there" which folder?  On the build server?

Comment: Surely it has to be on my development server, which it is, and then it is copied across to the build server?

Comment: I would verify that it's on the build server.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Files don't get copied from a dev server to a build server. The build-server gets all of its files from its own HDD or from TFS.  If those files aren't on the HDD of your build server, then that is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your build server is not automatically downloading the NuGet packages.  I'm assuming you're using NuGet since the build is looking for the dependency in a "packages" folder.

I would check out some of the following articles:

[Using Nuget and TFS Build 2010](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rfennell/archive/2011/10/17/using-nuget-and-tfs-build-2010.aspx)

[NuGet and TFS 2010 Automated Build](http://www.centrolutions.com/blog/post/2012/07/05/NuGet-and-TFS-2010-Automated-Build.aspx)

Comment: Well the first link you give seems to match my problem completely. However when I got to " I then pressed the add files button", there wasn't one. I ended up checking in the EF dll, but that was not really what the link said and it didn't work.

Comment: It should be labelled "Add items to folder".  You could also try adding the folder from Visual Studio by right-clicking the folder in Solution Explorer and selecting "Add to Source Control".

Comment: I do not know if this is the perfect solution, but your answer helped me in my way. I created a library; lib for each project with all the third party libraries. And now it builds. So thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check NTFS permissions for the account that you are using for your build controller.
To troubleshoot, try logging into your build machine using the account for your build controller and see if you can find those paths and make your own build manually.