# Cannot remove reference to EF version 6 in build

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, msbuild

I am using TFS 2010 and VS 2012.

I failed in my attempt to upgrade MVC4 to MVC5. I thought I rolled back my project OK in TFS but my builds fail because the references to EF version 6 have not all been removed.

As far as I can tell I have removed EF v6 everywhere in my code. However in my build I have the following message;

> Unified primary reference "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
>   Using this version instead of original version "4.4.0.0" in "C:\Builds\3\solutionA\solutionA- Test\Sources\projectB\projectB\bin\Debug\projectB.dll" because AutoUnify is 'true'.
>   Resolved file path is "C:\Builds\3\solutionA\solutionA - Test\Sources\MVC4\solutionA\solutionA.Model\lib\EntityFramework.dll".
>   Reference found at search path location "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".

So what does "AutoUnify is true" mean?

Comment: did you use Nuget to add this package? It looks like an attribute Nuget ads to the proj file, may not be automatically deleted, you may need to update the proj file manually.  Let me know if this is the issue and i'll add an answer with more details. check out this link http://colinbul.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/appharbour-and-nuget-and-f/

Comment: I did use Nuget and I did look in the proj file and I could not find any references to EF v6

Comment: two follow up questions, did you remove the package through Nuget? and have you checked the packages.config?

Comment: Yes to both questions. I have done a Ctrl F search for 6.0.0 to find if there are any references to EF v6, and there are none. But the build suggests there are.

Comment: when you say build you mean your local build option inside of Visual Studio, not a remote build server, correct?  with all of the other questions not pointing to a problem, I'll take a shot in the dark.  The AutoUnify may be a nuget parameter, reading your exception literally, it appears nuget/your proj file recognizes the version is 4.4.0.0, but it's opting for a newer version 6.0.0.0 that it is finding in a local folder.  Look at the second path stated in the exception see if there is an errant copy of the EF dll?

Comment: you could try removing local copies of the EF dll, and re-grabbing the version you want from nuget? ultimately it seems like an out of sync version still exists and is being chosen errantly by your build function

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstallin EF version 5 from Nuget. Instead of using the EF dll in my local lib folder, I am using the version in the packages folder which it uses by default; ..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll.
Now this works fine on my local PC, but when I try to build it via TFS the EF dll is missing, I get "warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to make a proper answer from our comments.  I think this initial problem was an out of sync dll, from the packages folder.  You re-installed EF 5 fresh were still having packages issues.

This appears to also be something with your Nuget setup.  This SO article is the same error as your latest build error. [Build cannot find entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878675/build-cannot-find-entity-framework) .

In particular this article from the accepted answer sounds very similar to the issues you're having. http://msmvps.com/blogs/rfennell/archive/2011/10/17/using-nuget-and-tfs-build-2010.aspx especially to your point that it works locally, but not in the build process.  Let me know if your issues seems different.

Comment: When I looked in the Source Control Explorer I found the reference to EF was not there. Maybe it had been deleted when upgrading to EF 6 and deleted again when reverting back to EF 5. So I got the deleted items to display and restored the EF 5 folder in Source Control Explorer and checked it in. The build was then able to get the correct version of EF.